# How to do a json query in C#?

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am using SQL Server 2017 which has Json support. However I am using EF core which cannot query json.

How am I to do queries then?

Example

```
  SELECT
      *, JSON_VALUE (Attributes, '$.year') AS Year
  FROM 
      items
  WHERE 
      JSON_VALUE(Attributes, '$.year') = '2017'
```

How would I query this in C# / ASP.NET Core? ADO.NET?

Comment: Kindly refer this link https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm.

Comment: Can you not write a storedproc on the sqlserver side and call that from EF?

Comment: You have to write raw queries, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: @DavidG - I saw that but what confuses me is since it is json so should my model have every single json property in it? How do they get mapped together?

Comment: Well you can only do this for types that are already a `DbSet` in your context. If you want to run other ad-hoc queries, you need another method outside of EF Core.

Comment: well, I have the column name in my DbSet but it's all the json properties that I want to access. Or do I have to first query it and then extract the values out after?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `items` is a model like below:

```
    public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

If so and you do not need `Year`, you could try `FromSql` like below:

```
string sQuery = "SELECT *, JSON_VALUE (Attributes, '$.year') AS Year FROM  Customer WHERE JSON_VALUE(Attributes, '$.year') = '2018'";               

var customerEF = await _context.Customer.FromSql(sQuery).ToListAsync();
```

For this way, you could only return columns which is defined in `Customer` model.

If you want to return columns in `Customer` and `Year` column, I suggest you try [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) like:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
        {                
            string sQuery = "SELECT *, JSON_VALUE (Attributes, '$.year') AS Year FROM  Customer WHERE JSON_VALUE(Attributes, '$.year') = '2018'";
            var customerDapper = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<CustomerVM>(sQuery);                           
        }
```

With `Dapper`, define new model with `Year` column:

```
    public class CustomerVM: Customer
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

Avoid SQL inection.

Try passing SQL parameters.

```
string sQuery = "SELECT *, JSON_VALUE (Attributes, '$.year') AS Year FROM  Customer WHERE JSON_VALUE(Attributes, '$.year') = @Year";
var year = new SqlParameter("Year", "2018");
var customerEF = await _context.Customer.FromSql(sQuery, year).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Yea this is what I sort of ended up doing is using EF and then once I get the attributes back I just then json.net parse it.  Right now I hardcoded 2018 in the where caluse how can I put a parameter in that will not open up sql inject attacks?

Comment: @chobo2 You could try passing parameters to avoid sql inject attacks. Check my update answer.